# Is it possible to have a function that gets any data frame and any column as its inputs using Pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine we have a dataframe like this:

```
 my_df>>  

  column_1   column_2 column_3  column_4
0  0.276162  0.552951  0.866023  0.571535
1  0.112933  0.549487  0.626958  0.988705
2  0.916932  0.561641  0.220696  0.545019
```

Can I have a function that can get any dataframe like this one with any column of it as its input?

To clarify better, if I have a function like this:

```
def multiply_5(df,column):
    df.column=df.column.apply(lambda x:x*5-3)
```

Does it work if I use it any similar way like this? :

```
multiply_5(my_df,column_2)
```

in order to get this:

```
my_df.column_2=my_df.column_2.apply(lambda x:x*5-3)
```

I know this specific way I wrote does not work, but is there any easy way to use this function for other data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def multiply_5(df,column):
    df[column]=df[column].apply(lambda x:x*5-3)
    return df

df = multiply_5(df, "column_2")

print(df)
    column_1    column_2    column_3    column_4
0   0.276162    -4.176225   0.866023    0.571535
1   0.112933    -4.262825   0.626958    0.988705
2   0.916932    -3.958975   0.220696    0.545019
```

Even a weirder way to do the same thing through attributes:

```
def multiply_5(df,column):
    setattr(df,column, getattr(df,column).apply(lambda x:x*5-3))
    return df
```

Comment: Thanks, as you said I had to replace df.column with df[column].

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't even need such a function - you can use [DataFrame.eval()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html) function:

Data:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4
0  0.276162  0.552951  0.866023  0.571535
1  0.112933  0.549487  0.626958  0.988705
2  0.916932  0.561641  0.220696  0.545019
```

Demo:

```
In [7]: df.eval("column_1 = column_1 * 5", inplace=False)
Out[7]:
   column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4
0  1.380810  0.552951  0.866023  0.571535
1  0.564665  0.549487  0.626958  0.988705
2  4.584660  0.561641  0.220696  0.545019

In [8]: df.eval("new = (column_1 + column_3) ** 2", inplace=False)
Out[8]:
   column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4       new
0  0.276162  0.552951  0.866023  0.571535  1.304587
1  0.112933  0.549487  0.626958  0.988705  0.547439
2  0.916932  0.561641  0.220696  0.545019  1.294197

In [9]: df.eval("new = sqrt(sin(column_2))", inplace=False)
Out[9]:
   column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4       new
0  0.276162  0.552951  0.866023  0.571535  0.724707
1  0.112933  0.549487  0.626958  0.988705  0.722669
2  0.916932  0.561641  0.220696  0.545019  0.729778
```